# If string meets a pattern then edit R

Tags: regex, r, string, expression

I have a large list of data. I want to edit it according to some pattern recognition. 
For example:

if I have a letter then I want to print that letter and some additional characters after.

If I have some numbers I want to print the numbers and some additional characters after.

If I have a unique character like "@" "#" "/" and/or ":" Then I want to subsitute it with a space.

If I have n (n being a number like 9) numbers then n (n being a number) characters then I want to print what I have and add some letters or characters to the end of the string.

```
So let a data set be
data  output
F       F State
M       M State
R       R State
55      55 Object
53      53 Object
993M@L  99M L Object
93283M  93283M State0
```

I think it would be similar to a ifelse(if there are 5 numbers followed 1 letter, original space State0,NA)

I would also like the NA,so that way I can see in my data what does not match the rules that I make.

This is my first time working on this and I am researching but most of the resources are not for R.
Any additional help is great!

Comment: are you pasting "State" and "Object" randomly? `gsub('(\\d+)(.*)', '\\1 \\2', gsub('[@#/:]', ' ', paste(dd$data, 'State')), perl = TRUE)
`

Comment: No State and Object correspond to certain letter and number format combinations.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following function with `grepl` and `gsub`:

```
test<-function(str){
    if(grepl("^[A-Z]$", str, perl=TRUE)){
        gsub("^([A-Z])$", "\\1 State", str)
    }
    else if(grepl("^\\d+$", str, perl=TRUE)){
        gsub("^(\\d+)$", "\\1 Object", str)
    }
    else if(grepl("[@#/:]", str, perl=TRUE)){
        str<-gsub("[@#/:]", " ", str)
        paste(str," Object")
    }
    else if(grepl("^\\d+[A-Z]+$", str, perl=TRUE)){
        gsub("^(\\d+[A-Z]+)$", "\\1 State0", str)
    }
}

x<-"F"
x<-test(x)
print(x)        //output: "F State"

x<-"55"
x<-test(x)
print(x)        //output: "55 Object"

x<-"993M@L"
x<-test(x)
print(x)        //output: "993M L  Object"

x<-"93283M"
x<-test(x)
print(x)        //output: "93283M State0"
```

Comment: That looks like something I can use.  Also how do I add an output NA if the string does not conform to any of the rules above? How do I tell it to look for a certain number of numbers before looking for letters?

Comment: I also want to use this formula on a large list of values, but when use X<-"df$V1" it is printing NULL.

Comment: @user_n add another line at the end that says `else NA`. to use on a large list, you could vectorize this function or just use the function `Vectorize`: `v <- Vectorize(test); v(c('F','55','993M@L','9328M'))`

Comment: Warning messages:
1: In if (grepl("^[A-Z]$", str, perl = TRUE)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (grepl("^\\d+$", str, perl = TRUE)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (grepl("[@#/:]", str, perl = TRUE)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
4: In if (grepl("^\\d+[A-Z]+$", str, perl = TRUE)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: I am getting these warnings for some reason. Also                                     }
    else if(grepl("^\\d+[A-Z]+$", str, perl=TRUE)){
        gsub("^(\\d+[A-Z]+)$", "\\1 State0", str)
    }
}                                                                                                                  Is it possible to ask the code if there are 6 numbers then 3 letters then the rest past the following, or if there are 6 number then 2 letter do something else? I understand a little how gsub is working but I would like grepl1 to consider the number of characters as well.